# Macro insert formula across columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a formula across all columns (Column B to last column with data) based on value in Column A.

Below is what I have so far:

```
Sub Insert_Falldown_Ratio_Formula()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long


lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For lRow = lLastRow To 2 Step -1

    If Cells(lRow, "A").Value = "Falldown Ratio"
        Set Rng = Range("B" & (1Row) & ":" & lastcolumn)
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(RC[-1],2)=""45"",""45'"",IF(RIGHT(RC[-1],1)=""Q"",""40'HC"",LEFT(RC[-1],2)&""'""))"

    End If
Next lRow
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things. (1) You were missing a Then on your If line (2) in the following line you had `1Row` instead of `lRow` and (3) you were copying down rather than across.

```
Sub Insert_Falldown_Ratio_Formula()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For lRow = lLastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow, "A").Value = "Falldown Ratio" Then
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(lRow, "B"), Cells(lRow, lastcolumn))
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(RC[-1],2)=""45"",""45'"",IF(RIGHT(RC[-1],1)=""Q"",""40'HC"",LEFT(RC[-1],2)&""'""))"
    End If
Next lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!